# jsPlumb Connection event is triggering more than once

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am working on a project. So what I am doing here is that in jsPlumb I am dynamically loading DIV elements on screen, and when I am trying to establish connection between any 2 elements then the connection event is triggering as many times as there are number of dynamically loaded DIV elements on screen, while I want it to trigger only once.

Here is my code for above description:

```
$('#container').dblclick(function(e) {
var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + i).addClass('item');

var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text('State ' + i);
var connect = $('<div>').addClass('connect');

newState.css({
  'top': e.pageY,
  'left': e.pageX
});

jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
  anchor: 'Continuous'
});

jsPlumb.makeSource(connect, {
  parent: newState,
  anchor: 'Continuous'
});

newState.append(title);
newState.append(connect);

$('#container').append(newState);

jsPlumb.draggable(newState, {
   containment: 'parent'
});

jsPlumb.bind("connection", function (info, originalEvent) {

        alert(info.sourceId);
}); 
i++;
```

The event connection in `jsPlumb.bind()` is triggering more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to solve it by moving the `jsPlumb.bind` listener before and outside the loop that was setting up each draggable div element. 
For example, I have a `configureTool` function that is called for each div element I want to make draggable:

```
$('.display > .draggableTool').each(function(idx) {
    configureTool($(this));
}
```

In the configureTool function I set up the jsPlumb elements:

```
function configureTool($el) {
     /* initialize jsPlumb draggable elements */
    jsPlumb.draggable($el, {
        containment:"parent"
    });

    /* set up source and give it parameters to work with */
    jsPlumb.makeSource($el, {
        /* parameters.... */
        }
    });

    /* initialise all elements with '.draggableTool' class as connection targets */
    jsPlumb.makeTarget($el, {
        anchor:"Continuous"
    });

    /* move jsPlumb.bind("connection", function()) before configureTool loop */
}
```

By moving the connection listener before the loop calling the `configureTool` function, I was able to fix the extra event triggers. 
So it ends up looking like this:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(info, originalEvent) {
    alert(info.sourceId);
});

$('.display > .draggableTool').each(function(idx) {
    configureTool($(this));
});
```

Hopefully I understood your question and this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes adding the

```
     instance.bind("connection", function(info) {

            alert(info.sourceId);

        });
```

outside of the loop is the solution.